# Counting number of records in database: Django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to output the count of the number of "subscribers" in my database in Django, I've found count in my view and then I think I'm using it correctly in the html, but it always just outputs "there are subscribers" without the number, when I use "|length" in the html it always outputs 0, so I'm not sure what my error is.

**views.py**

```
def list_todo_items(request):
    context = {'todo_list' : Todo.objects.all()}
    count = Todo.objects.count()
    context2 = {'count': count}
    # context = {'count': Todo.objects.count()}
    # count = Todo.objects.count()
    return render(request, 'index.html',context,context2)

def insert_todo_item(request: HttpRequest):
    todo = Todo(content=request.POST['content'])
    try:
        todo.full_clean()

    except ValidationError:
        # pymsgbox.alert('ValidationError! Phone number must be entered in the format: +999999999. Up to 15 digits allowed.', 'Title')
        return redirect('/main/list/')

    todo.save()
    return redirect('/main/list/')

def delete_todo_item(request,todo_id):
    todo_to_delete = Todo.objects.get(id=todo_id)
    todo_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('/main/list/')
```

**index.html**

```
{% for todo in todo_list %}
    <li class="list-group-item"> {{todo.content}}

    <form action="{% url 'delete_todo_item' todo.id %}" method="post" class="float-right d-inline">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn">
            <i class="far fa-trash-alt fa-lg text-danger float-right"></i>
        </button>
    </form>

</li>

<li class="list-group-item">
    <span class="font-italic">There are {{ count }} subscribers.</span>
</li>

{% empty %}
<li class="list-group-item">
     <span class="font-italic">No current subscribers.</span>
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass multiple items to the *same* context. A dictionary allows to add multiple key-value pairs (as long as the keys are hashable, and unique):

```
def list_todo_items(request):
    context = {
        'todo_list': Todo.objects.all(),
        'count': Todo.objects.count()
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```